# Is Drupal 4.7 compatible with Mysql 5.1 and PHP 5.3

Tags: database

I am having some strange problems with Drupal 4.7.11 on my local machine. Before I get into it I should give you some context. I am running PHP 5.3.4 and MySQL 5.1.54.

If I try to run Drupal 4.7 without any DB info it comes up to a screen that asks me to put in the DB connect info. Once I do that I get a white screen in my browser and in terminal running cron.php I get a DB connect error.

Now as I was writing this I realized that PHP 5.3 is probably a problem here. But I might as well ask anyway.

So thoughts on compatibility?

UPDATE: I realized that my machine is running two different versions of PHP because I am on a Mac and it has 5.3. However, my Apache is running from Zend Desktop which is 5.2. So the site is setup in 5.2 right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that both may be an issue. PHP definitely is. I'm not sure about Mysql.

Drupal 4.7 is quite a few versions out of date and it is no longer being maintained. You really should be looking to use a more recent version.

Comment: May be he is trying to upgrade old site to latest version.

Comment: Probably, but I thought it was worth saying just in case.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I only need this to work long enough to be able to inspect the nodes on the old sites. I am migrating multiple Drupal 4.7 sites into one big Drupal 6 site. So my purpose here is write migration scripts for organic groups, users, and content.

Answer (score 3):

Only Drupal 6 (from 6.14 onward) and Drupal 7 are compatible with PHP 5.3.

Comment: Not all D6 contrib modules work with PHP 5.3.  5.2 is the recommended version for D6 per http://drupal.org/requirements#php

Comment: That is correct, but the thing is that the only officially maintained PHP version is now 5.3. There will be no more new security updates for PHP 5.2 unless you are using a packages version by your OS or a similar distribution.

Comment: I am actually running PHP 5.2 on my local server. I got mixed up between the version that terminal was using and the version that Apache was using. My mistake.